# Using Min in Update statement to get oldest record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update my tableA with tableB but get only those records from table B having the oldest entry

```
TableA:
name ID
nick 15
john 12

tableB:
ID sportsname createddate
12 tennis     15march2019
14 baseball   15march2019
15 basketball 16march2019
15 cricket    20march2020
15 football   17may2020
```

My query:

```
update a
set a.sportsname=b.sportsname
from tablea a join tableb b 
on a.id=b.id where b.createdate=( select min(createdate) from tableb )
```

But this is not giving correct result

Comment: Do you want the oldest entry *overall* or per `id`?

Comment: oldest entry per id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update a
set a.name=b.sportsname
from @T a join (select min(createddate) as min_createddate,ID,sportsname from @t2  
group by ID,sportsname) b ON b.ID=a.ID
```

You can use a **SUB QUERY** to attain this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem with your query is that you are using the minimum create date over the entire `tableb` rather than per `id`.  Although you could fix that using a correlated subquery, I would recommend `apply`:

```
update a
    set a.sportsname = b.sportsname
    from tablea a cross apply
         (select top (1) b.*
          from tableb b 
          where a.id = b.id 
          order by b.createdate asc
         ) b;
```

For performance, you want an index on `tableb(id, createdate desc, sportname)`.

Comment: this query is taking too much time to run , can be there any more efficient one

Comment: @rajiv . . . That could be because you are updating all the rows, and that takes time.  However, the index will speed the querying part of the query (as opposed to the "update" part).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) window function:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.sportsname=b.sportsname
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
    FIRST_VALUE(sportsname) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY createddate) sportsname
  FROM TableB
) b ON b.ID = a.ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60ae388e77b92b9736bdfc883f639838).